# Rails 4: "wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller, actionmailer

I know this is a pretty standard error, but I could not figure out a solution to this particular solution from other questions.

I am following this coderwall tutorial about *[Creating a Scoped Invitation System for Rails](https://coderwall.com/p/rqjjca/creating-a-scoped-invitation-system-for-rails)*.

I have four models, as follows:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :administrations
  has_many :calendars, through: :administrations
  has_many :invitations, :class_name => "Invite", :foreign_key => 'recipient_id'
  has_many :sent_invites, :class_name => "Invite", :foreign_key => 'sender_id'
end

class Calendar < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :administrations
  has_many :users, through: :administrations
  has_many :invites
end

class Administration < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :calendar
end

class Invite < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :calendar
  belongs_to :sender, :class_name => 'User'
  belongs_to :recipient, :class_name => 'User'
end
```

And this is the migration for the `Invite` model:

```
class CreateInvites < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :invites do |t|
      t.string :email 
      t.integer :calendar_id
      t.integer :sender_id
      t.integer :recipient_id
      t.string :recipient_role
      t.string :token
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

The goal of the `Invite` model is to allow `User`s to invite other `User`s to join a particular `Calendar`.

The `create` `Invite` form is embedded in the `Calendar` `edit` view, as follows:

```
<h2>Edit <%= @calendar.name %> calendar</h2>

<%= render 'form' %>

<h2>Invite new users to <%= @calendar.name %> calendar</h2>

<%= form_for @invite , :url => invites_path do |f| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :calendar_id, :value => @invite.calendar_id %>
    <%= f.label :email %>
    <%= f.email_field :email %>
    <%= f.label "Role" %>
    <%= f.radio_button(:recipient_role, "Editor") %>
    <%= f.label "Editor" %>
    <%= f.radio_button(:recipient_role, "Viewer") %>
    <%= f.label "Viewer" %>
    <%= f.submit 'Send' %>
<% end %>

<%= link_to 'Show', calendar_path %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', calendars_path %>
```

Here is the corresponding `Calendars#Edit`:

```
def edit
  @user = current_user
  @invite = @calendar.invites.build
  authorize @calendar
end
```

And here is the `InvitesController`:

```
class InvitesController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @invite = Invite.new(invite_params) # Make a new Invite
    @invite.sender_id = current_user.id # set the sender to the current user
    if @invite.save
      InviteMailer.invite(@invite, new_user_registration_path(:invite_token => @invite.token)).deliver #send the invite data to our mailer to deliver the email
    else
      format.html { render :edit, notice: 'Invitation could not be sent.' }
    end
  end

  private

  def invite_params
    params.require(:invite).permit(:email)
  end

end
```

Last but not least, here is the `InviteMailer`:

```
class InviteMailer < ApplicationMailer

  def invite(invite)
    @link = new_user_registration_path invite_token: invite.token
    mail to: invite.email, subject: "Calendy Invitation"
  end

end
```

When I visit `http://localhost:3000/calendars/3/edit` and submit the `Invite` `create` form, I get the following error:

```
ArgumentError in InvitesController#create
wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)

class InviteMailer < ApplicationMailer

  def invite(invite)
    @link = new_user_registration_path invite_token: invite.token
    mail to: invite.email, subject: "Calendy Invitation"
  end
```

My instinct would be to replace:

```
InviteMailer.invite(@invite, new_user_registration_path(:invite_token => @invite.token)).deliver
```

With:

```
InviteMailer.invite(@invite).deliver
```

But I am not sure this is actually the right solution.

Any idea about how to fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My instinct would be to replace:
>
> ```
> InviteMailer.invite(@invite, new_user_registration_path(:invite_token => @invite.token)).deliver
> ```
>
> With:
>
> ```
> InviteMailer.invite(@invite).deliver
> ```

Yes, that would be fine, since you're doing the same - your `InviteMailer#invite` stores this data itself in `@link` variable:

```
class InviteMailer < ApplicationMailer

  def invite(invite)
    @link = new_user_registration_path invite_token: invite.token
    mail to: invite.email, subject: "Calendy Invitation"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

May be changing the `invite` to allow an extra argument like below should work too

```
class InviteMailer < ApplicationMailer
  def invite(invite, link)
    @link = link
    mail to: invite.email, subject: "Calendy Invitation"
  end
end
```